# Merge two datasets in R

Tags: r

I have two different datasets arranged in column format as follows:

Dataset 1:

```
A   B   C   D   E

13  1   1.7 2   1
13  2   5.3 2   1
13  2   2   2   1
13  2   1.8 2   1
1   6   27  9   1
1   6   6.6 9   1
1   7   17  9   1
1   7   7.1 9   1
1   7   8.5 9   1
```

Dataset 2:

```
A   B   F   G
13  1   42  1002
13  2   42  1002
13  2   42  1002
13  2   42  1002
13  3   42  1002
13  4   42  1002
13  5   42  1002
1   2   27  650
1   3   27  650
1   4   27  650
1   6   27  650
1   7   27  650
1   7   27  650
1   7   27  650
1   8   27  650
```

Row numbers of both datasets are variable but they contain data for two samples (for example, column A: 13 and 1 of both datasets). I want C D and E values of dataset 1 to be placed in dataset 2, those having the same values of A and B in both datasets. So, joining should be based on A and B. I need to do this for about 47560 rows.

I am new in R so should be thankful if I could get code for saving the new merged dataset in R.

Comment: If you are doing a merge on A and B and in one file you have three instances with A=13;B=2 and in the other file you have 3 others with those values, then you will get nine rows. Is that what you expected?

Comment: I need 6 rows of which 3 rows filled in and 3 will be NA. Row number of merged database should be identical with dataset2

Comment: That specification is incomprehensible, to me anyway. You need to more completely explain, because the two "ordinary choices" would have been to butt them side-to-side (for 3 rows) or to return the Cartesian-product. You have something else in mind, but you have not explained it. Edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use the merge function in R.

Reference from : http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

Edit:
So first you'd need to read in the datasets, CSV is a good format.

```
> dataset1 <- read.csv(file="dataset1.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",") 
> dataset2 <- read.csv(file="dataset2.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")
```

If you just type the variable names now and hit enter you should see a read-out of your datasets. So...

```
> dataset1
```

should read out your data above. Then I believe the following should occur...I may be wrong...

```
> dataset1_2 <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by=c("A","B"))
```

EDIT 2 :

```
> write.table(dataset1_2, "c:/dataset1_2.txt", sep=" ")
```

Reference : http://www.statmethods.net/input/exportingdata.html

Comment: I feel like this should be similar to what you're looking for...
total <- merge(data frameA,data frameB,by=c("A","B"))

Comment: Thanks. But how to work with two datasets in R. Could I please request to provide the codes using this example datasets

Comment: Do you mean to a separate text file?

Comment: This site is for professional and enthusiast programmers. You are expected to try reading the documentation first and then try to write some code, please.

Comment: I agree, but I had fun helping him/her out.

Comment: Could OP please select my suggestion as the answer if it worked out?